# FileHelper can't handle ReSharper sorting variables in its classes

Tags: c#, resharper, filehelpers

I have code doing this:

```
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<SampleType>();
var records = engine.ReadString("asdf|fdsa");

var showString = records[0].Field1 + records[0].Field2;
```

The SampleType class looks like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class SampleType
{
    public string Field2;
    public string Field1;
}
```

The resultset is as follows:

`records[0].Field1` has the value `fdsa`

`records[0].Field2` has the value `asdf`

If I run a ReSharper cleanup it will sort the variables alphabetically. And the SampleType class will look like this:

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public class SampleType
{
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
}
```

But now the logic of my program has changed.

`records[0].Field1` has the value `asdf`

`records[0].Field2` has the value `fdsa`

Is there a way to tell the classes that the order of the defined variables is irrelevant? That the defining order of variables is suddenly relevant, contrary to any other class I have ever seen, I find very disturbing and strange.

Comment: I think you have two options, 1) stop ReSharper suggesting this as an improvement or 2) have the fields in alphabetical order in the first place.

Comment: Keep in mind that the code is a reproduction of what I found in our solution (Title is after Author in the alphabet, but Title comes first in the csv file). What you are saying then is that this library is poorly written? I think I'll make a case for dropping it if there is no alternative to always being eagle eyed when using ReSharper when this library is around.

Comment: I'm not saying that the library is poorly written. The ordering of the fields is (in the actual case) seems to be sensible. Therefore in this case it would seem that your only option is to turn off this feature of ReSharper in this case.

Comment: May I ask why this solution is sensible? As far as I can see It goes against everything we have previously learned about classes in C# and OOP in general. The way I understand it it takes C# into the functional area. If we go this way we might expect the order of defined methods in a class to execute in the order they are defined too... Is that not a bad smell?

Comment: I think you might be overthinking this. The issue appears to be caused by the assumption of order in the file, where meaning is dependent on value. Ideally you'd change the file to make it flexible. However, if you really can't change the file then you are going to have live with this.

Comment: Well. The file is from a third party, and this is why the question is here on SO. The original question is "Is there a way to tell the classes that the order of the defined variables is irrelevant", so I do understand that if this question is not answered, I'll have to live with it. However I am quite surprised of how OK this way of solving a problem in such a library seems to you. And for the record, this is not logical, and to be able to understand it, you'll have to "overthink" :p It's not a part of the languages design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I *think* you want a way to make FileHelpers use an explicitly-specified ordering for the fields, rather than the implicit 'the order they are defined in in the source'.

If I'm right, you want [the `FieldOrder` attribute](http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Attributes/FieldOrder/) from the FileHelpers library:

> ### Force field order with [FieldOrder] attribute:
>
> ```
> //-> You first declare a Record Mapping class:
> Input.txt
>
> 10248|VINET|04071996|32.38
> 10249|TOMSP|05071996|11.61
> 10250|HANAS|08071996|65.83
> 10251|VICTE|08071996|41.34
>
>
> RecordClass.cs
>
> [DelimitedRecord("|")]
> public class Orders
> {
>     [FieldOrder(20)]
>     public string CustomerID;
>
>     [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "ddMMyyyy")]
>     [FieldOrder(30)]
>     public DateTime OrderDate;
>
>     [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Decimal, ".")] // The decimal separator is "."
>     [FieldOrder(40)]
>     public decimal Freight;
>
>     [FieldOrder(10)]
>     public int OrderID;
> }
> ```

As to your comment

> However I am quite surprised of how OK this way of solving a problem
>   in such a library seems to you. And for the record, this is not
>   logical, and to be able to understand it, you'll have to "overthink"
>   :p It's not a part of the languages design

You're right in that the default operation mode of FileHelper here (to use the source-ordering of fields as their in-record ordering) isn't 'native' C#, and indeed isn't a particularly 'C#-ish' way of doing things; BUT that's OK if it's how the authors and users of FileHelpers want it. It does have the flavour of a more dynamic-language style, but then that's *a bit* how C# is headed anyway...

Comment: Perfect! FileOrder it is :D And I guess I am a bit hard headed when it comes to following the languages guidelines in objects. One thing would be if this was my personal library and no one but me would have to understand it. Difference is when everyone else has to understand it, and implicit things are done, that are not easy to understand. Saying that it's OK if the authors want it makes for a lot of hard-to-use libraries in the future... :) Granted, as long as it has [FileOrder(10)] options, i have no problems with it :)